# GCP Cloud Function, where express config is async

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions

I have an express server that I want to use in a serverless Cloud Function. I want to enable the [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs). As the tutorial says, I need to refactor the configuration of my server to an `async` function.

Previously, the way I made my express app work in cloud function, was to just export the express app as `entrypoint`, which I provided as the name in my function config as well, and it was all working well (meaning if I run `npx functions-framework --target=entrypoint`, I could reach the server).

Now, that I refactored my config to a `const startServer = async() => {...; return app;}`, I can't seem to be able to make it work correctly. I tried exporting:

- `export entrypoint = startServer`
- `export entrypoint = startServer()`
- `export entrypoint = async startServer()`

but nothing seems to yield the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't supported.  And the code in the documentation you're looking at does not apply to Cloud Functions - it is only for standalone nodejs apps (which can't be run in Cloud Functions) that want to use Cloud Logging internally.

In fact, GCP Cloud Functions can't run an express app at all.  It only allows you to define individual function endpoints as you see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-nodejs).

If you want to deploy an express app to Cloud Functions, your best bet is to use the Firebase CLI to deploy the app.  Firebase has special tooling that understands how to deploy an express app as a function.  A simple example is shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd#using_existing_express_or_flask_apps).

That said, Firebase does not support async configuration of an express app.  The app needs to be directly exported from your index.js so the CLI knows exactly what it needs to deploy without waiting on other stuff to happen first.

Comment: does structured logging work from logs on stdout?

Comment: No idea, never used it as it's documented.  If you're going to write Cloud Functions using Firebase, look into this, which I can tell you does print to stdout during development: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs?gen=2nd